# Is it possible to get bash to display the first letter of each directory in my working path?

Tags: bash, prompt

For example working in:

```
/home/stuart/src/project/com/example/package
/usr/lib/python2.6
```

would appear as:

```
~/s/p/c/e/package$ 
/u/l/python2.6$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497885/code-challenge-bash-prompt-path-shortener).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
export PS1='$(echo $(dirname \w)|sed -e "s;\(/.\)[^/]*;\1;g")/$(basename \w) $ '
```

Comment: Great thanks. I've updated it to:

`export PS1='$(echo $(dirname \w)|sed -e "s;\(/\.\?.\)[^/]*;\1;g" -e "s;/h/s;~;")/\W\$ '`

So that dot dirs keep a "." and a character. I also replace "/h/s" (/home/stuart) with a "~".

Comment: Second update: `export PS1='$(echo $(dirname $(echo \w | sed "s;$HOME;~;"))/ |sed -e "s;\(/\.\?.\)[^/]*;\1;g" -e "s;/h/s;~;" -e "s;\./;;")\W\$ '` Adds some more hacks so that it looks good in the home dir.

Comment: And now I've discovered there are far too many edge cases for this approach to work the way I want (root dir, in home dir, being below home dir). It's still very elegant though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my go at it, based on *Mat*'s answer. Avoids problems in corner cases such as `/` and `~`.

```
PS1='`echo "${PWD%/*}" | sed -e "s;\(/.\)[^/]*;\1;g"`/${PWD##*/} \$ '
```

Replace `.` with `..` to display 2 letters.